# How to make Citrus FTP Host,Port,Username,Password with dynamic variables

Tags: cucumber, citrus-framework, citrus-engine

XML DSL

```
 <citrus-ftp:client id="ftpClient"
      host="${var1}"
      port="${var2}"
      username="${var3}"
      password="${var4}"
      timeout="10000"/>
```

Steps.XML

```html
<spring:beans xmlns="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/cucumber/testcase"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    
    xmlns:citrus="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase"
    
    xmlns:citrus-ftp="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/ftp/config"
    
   
    xmlns:citrus-http="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config" 
    
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    
     http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/cucumber/testcase 
     
     http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/cucumber/testcase/citrus-cucumber-testcase.xsd 
    
    http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config
    
    http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config/citrus-http-config.xsd
    
   
    http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/ftp/config
   
  
    http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/ftp/config/citrus-ftp-config.xsd">

 <citrus-ftp:client id="ftpClient"
      host="${var1}"
      port="${var2}"
      username="${var3}"
      password="${var4}"
      timeout="10000"/>
 
    
      
<spring:import resource="FTP_Template.xml" />
<step given="^Test FTP connection">
<citrus:call-template name="MyFTP">
</citrus:call-template>
</step>
</spring:beans>
```

Cucumber Feature File

```
Scenario: Test FTP
        Given FTP Host:"localhost"
        Given FTP Port:"21"
        Given FTP Username:"ravi"
        Given FTP Password:"admin"
        Given Test FTP connection
```

I have a cucumber feature file. In the file, I am declared the variables FTP host port username password.
I need to make the feature file variables as an input to <citrus-ftp: client> to make dynamic configuration through feature files. Could anyone please help me with this

Comment: Could you please help me with this. @Christoph Deppisch

Comment: Hi Ravi,

We need more info to be able to help you.

You say you're using Cucumber, but what programming language? Ruby? Java? JavaScript? Something else?

What form do you want the XML to end up in? Do you just need it as a string in memory, or a file on disk?

What have you tried so far?

Comment: I developed the cucumber feature as above. I am declaring the step definitions in the file. Steps.xml <step given="^Test FTP connection">. These all are running in Java Spring Boot environment. where I am stuck is  need to pass feature file variable to the citrus FTP client as above.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help. I have neveer seen this use of XML like this for defining cucumber steps.

Comment: Maybe you could try asking in the #help-cucumber-jvm Slack channel: https://cucumberbdd.slack.com/archives/C5YHPPJMP

Comment: I am able to get the  cucumber feature file variable data to step files like as parnameter names  <step given="^My name is (.*)$" parameter-names="username">
    <citrus:create-variables>
      <citrus:variable name="username" value="${username}"/>
    </citrus:create-variables>
  </step>   But I need to input this variable values to citrus ftp client as above. I think I need to get help from the citrus  side like how to pass dynamic variables to FTP. Thanks